# How to shrink databases and claim more storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have created a SQL elastic pool but I have no more storage:

[image]

I run `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (N'db1')` on every single database to claim space following this guide: [Reduce Azure SQL Database Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829322/reduce-azure-sql-database-size) but it seems like I haven't gained any space.

Should I use `DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0)`?

I'm considering [Auto-shrink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/file-space-manage?view=azuresql#auto-shrink) but if the logic behind is the same of SHRINKDATABASE  there is no point to put it in place.

So how to claim unused space on SQL Elastic Pool?

Comment: *"The question is very easy. "* If it's so easy, why have you not posted an answer?

Comment: Because the question is very easy, the answer is very hard. But if you have one you can post one

Comment: “The most simple problems have simple solutions, easy to understand and to get wrong.” Arthur Bloch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution for Azure SQL Database was to setup [Auto-shrink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/file-space-manage?view=azuresql#auto-shrink):

```
-- Enable auto-shrink for the current database.
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET AUTO_SHRINK ON;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

first you need to gather information of your database, you need to know where you have spaces allocated that is not used, is it the DB files or DB log,
from this point you have two processes to follow,

1. if it is the log, you should first do a checkpoint and then take a transactional backup so the log can be emptied and you can shrink it,
   you can use
   DBCC Shrinkfile (, target size)
   find the file by help of sp_helpfile on your database
   if it didn't get smaller,
   use the query

select name , log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases
to understand what prevents it, the Log reuse wait desc should be "Nothing"
if there is anything, resolve that first.

2. if it is the database files, first you should find what database file it is,
   the GUI tools are better for this also there are script ways as well,
   but you can go to databases-> R-click on DB / tasks/shrink / files
   then check each file on FG for space available
   then you can shrink it to the least amount possible, but you better shrink it to a point that you don't expect the file to grow in a few days.

two important notes,

- do not use an auto shrink option on a production database that grows in-time. specially if you may have long transactions as you can not control when this auto shrink happens, happening it during a long transaction can lead to a major performance degrade.
- you may want to investigate, why such a thing happened in the first place, as it is very important to address this and resolve it.

you may also want to take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/file-space-manage?view=azuresql),
it has very good information about azure databases and the space they take and many of the things I mentioned in detail.

Answer (score -1):

Check your transaction log size - shrinking depends on your recovery model which deals with transaction log differently.

For SIMPLE recovery model, just a shrink should be enough:

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(dbname)
```

For FULL recovery mode, you can either switch to simple temporarily and do the above:

ALTER DATABASE dbname SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(dbname)
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET RECOVERY FULL

Or try releasing/discarding transaction log:

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(dbname)

BACKUP DATABASE dbname to disk='nul'
BACKUP LOG dbname to disk='nul'

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(dbname)
```

Comment: There is no Recovery Model in Azure SQL Database